# how can i insert in exit logs a data in sqlflite in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

/*I have a **flutter **code to register a student data and if i want to scan the qr code of the students it will show the modal and press the record entry or record exit so that the data will insert in EntryLogs or ExitLogs. my problem is if i add a u two user data and record the both of them in EntryLogs and ExitLogs the new data i want to insert in exitLogs are not inserted only the existing data are inserted. not the new data. here is my code.*/

```
void displayDetails() {
    final qrdetails = _qr_details
        .firstWhere((element) => element['qrCode'] == new_qrRegistration);
    qrcode = qrdetails['qrCode'];
    fullname = qrdetails['fullName'];
    courses = qrdetails['courses'];
    Uint8List _bytesImage;
    String _imgString = qrdetails['picture'];
    _bytesImage = Base64Decoder().convert(_imgString);

    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0))),
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.965,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 300.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                          radius: 152.0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            child: ClipOval(
                                child: new Image.memory(
                              _bytesImage,
                              width: 280.0,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            radius: 140.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 16.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'QR Code Identification Details',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 8.0,
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              thickness: 2.0,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 18.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                fullname!,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 38.0,
                                    color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Student",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 18.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                qrcode!,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 32.0,
                                    color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'ID Number',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 18.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                courses.toString().toUpperCase(),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 32.0,
                                    color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Course',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        _insertEntryLogs(context);
                                      },
                                      child: const Text(
                                        'RECORD ENTRY',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 18),
                                      ),
                                      style: ButtonStyle(
                                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                              Colors.teal),
                                          padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                              const EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                                  RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          16.0),
                                                  side: const BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.black54)))),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        int userId =
                                            1; // Change this to the actual userId you want to use
                                        _insertExitLogs(context, userId);
                                      },
                                      child: const Text(
                                        'RECORD EXIT    ',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 18),
                                      ),
                                      style: ButtonStyle(
                                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                              Colors.red),
                                          padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                              const EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                                  RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          16.0),
                                                  side: const BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.black54)))),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              thickness: 1.0,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '© College of Information and Communication Technology',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }``
```

/*i want to insert the new data in ExitLogs here is my code in Entry Logs screen*/

```
body: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
          Scaffold(
            body: _isLoading
                ? Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 18.0),
                      Center(
                        child: Text('No data found!'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _users.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Uint8List _bytesImage;
                      String _imgString = _users[index]['picture'];
                      _bytesImage = base64Decode(_imgString);

                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 11,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 7,
                                offset: Offset(0, 3),
                              ),
                            ],
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(12.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              radius: 34.0,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 26.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                child: ClipOval(
                                  child: _users[index]['picture'] != null
                                      ? Image.memory(
                                          _bytesImage,
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        )
                                      : Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              _users[index]['fullName'] ?? 'No Name',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              _users[index]['entrydate'] ?? 'No Date',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            trailing: SizedBox(
                              width: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    _users[index]['entrytime'] ?? 'No Time',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),
          Scaffold(
            body: _isLoadingExit
                ? Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 18.0),
                      Center(
                        child: Text('No data found!'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _usersExit.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
                      Uint8List _bytesImage;
                      String _imgString = _usersExit[index1]['picture'];
                      _bytesImage = base64Decode(_imgString);

                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 11,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 7,
                                offset: Offset(0, 3),
                              ),
                            ],
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(12.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              radius: 34.0,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 26.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                child: ClipOval(
                                  child: _bytesImage != null
                                      ? Image.memory(
                                          _bytesImage,
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        )
                                      : Container(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              _usersExit[index1]['fullName'] ?? 'No Name',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              _usersExit[index1]['exitdate'] ?? 'No Date',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            trailing: SizedBox(
                              width: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    _usersExit[index1]['exittime'] ?? 'No Time',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),
        ]),
```

/*i want someone can modify my **sql **helpers i think theres a problem with these its been a week since i research but i didnt get the output already*/

```
 static Future<int> insertEntry(
      int? userId, String? entry_date, String? entry_time) async {
    final db = await RegistrationSQLHelper.db();
    final data = {
      'user_id': userId,
      'entrydate': entry_date,
      'entrytime': entry_time,
    };
    final id = await db.insert('entrylogs', data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return id;
  }

  static Future<int> insertExit(
      int userId, String? exit_date, String? exit_time) async {
    final db = await RegistrationSQLHelper.db();
    final user = await db.query('users', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [userId]);

    if (user.isNotEmpty) {
      final data = {
        'user_id': userId,
        'exitdate': exit_date,
        'exittime': exit_time,
      };

      try {
        final id = await db.insert('exitlogs', data,
            conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
        return id;
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error inserting into exitlogs: $e');
        return -1; // Return -1 or handle appropriately
      }
    } else {
      print('User with id $userId does not exist');
      return -1; // Return -1 or handle appropriately
    }
 static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getEntryLogs() async {
    final db = await RegistrationSQLHelper.db();
    return db.rawQuery('''
    SELECT entrylogs.id, entrylogs.entrydate, entrylogs.entrytime, users.picture, users.fullName
    FROM entrylogs
    LEFT JOIN users ON entrylogs.user_id = users.id
    ORDER BY entrylogs.createdAt DESC
  ''');
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getExitLogs() async {
    final db = await RegistrationSQLHelper.db();
    return db.rawQuery('''
    SELECT exitlogs.id, exitlogs.exitdate, exitlogs.exittime, users.picture, users.fullName
    FROM exitlogs
    LEFT JOIN users ON exitlogs.user_id = users.id
    ORDER BY exitlogs.createdAt DESC
  ''');
  }
```